# C# Generic Parent Children Definition

Tags: c#, generics, design-patterns

I'm trying to design a parent/children definition in C#, but receive some compilation errors, which are not clear for me:

```
namespace TestProject1
{
    public abstract class BaseElement
    {
    }

    public abstract class Child<T> : BaseElement
    {
        public BaseElement Parent { get; set; }
    }

    public abstract class Parent<T> : BaseElement
    {
        public IQueryable<BaseElement> Children { get; set; }
    }

    public abstract class ParentChild<TParent, TChild> : BaseElement 
        where TParent : Parent<BaseElement> 
        where TChild : Child<BaseElement>
    {
        public void AddChild(TChild child)
        {
            child.Parent = this;
        }
    }

    public class Root : Parent<Trunk>
    {
    }

    public class Trunk : ParentChild<Root, Branch>
    {
    }

    public class Branch : ParentChild<Trunk, Leaf>
    {
    }

    public class Leaf : Child<Branch>
    {
    }
}
```

One of the compilation errors is in line *public class Trunk*:

> Error CS0311  The type `TestProject1.Root` cannot be used as type
>   parameter `TParent` in the generic type or method
>   `ParentChild<TParent, TChild>`. There is no implicit reference
>   conversion from `TestProject1.Root` to
>   `TestProject1.Parent<TestProject1.BaseElement>`.

But in fact there is a path from `Root` to `Parent<BaseElement>` as `Root` inherits from `Parent<Trunk>` and `Trunk` is a `BaseElement` due to the fact that `BaseElements` inherits from `ParentChild`, which is a direct successor from BaseElement.

The other compilation errors are similar, but for the `Branch` type in `Trunk` and the `Trunk` and `Leaf` parameters of `Branch`.

Comment: C# does not support variance for classes. Thus, `Parent<Trunk>` is not `Parent<BaseElement>`, regardless of relation between `Trunk` and `BaseElement`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the inheritance from `BaseElement` at play here.  You would have this same problem if none of these classes derived from `BaseElement`.  The type definition of `Root` depends on `Trunk`.  The type definition of `Trunk` depends on `Root`.  You can't have a circular dependency like that with generics in C#.  Effectively you are trying to define Root as `Root<Parent<ParentChild<Root, Branch>>>` so Root derives from Root, which is a problem.